# jQuery / css - Customize default horizontal scroll bar

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins, scrollbar

I got a **horizontal scrollbar** to scroll through a list of images. *I wish to style the scrollbar better* so it dint mess up my design. But, I cannot change much the html construct for some reasons.

My html is just a simple div wrapping around a list of images:

```
<div id="containersimg">
   <img...>
   <img...>
</div>
```

I had googled and tried 10++ jQuery plugins for either scrollbar or change it into a "carousel" like slider, but almost all required the ul and li tag, or some just simply alter the whole styling and position.

I hope can get some simple way / plugin to just make the scrollbar looks nicer. Feasible carousel plugin is also preferred. Hope there is someone here who had been using similar plugins and feel it nice.

Comment: I think you are going to need to provide more information to be able to get some help on this one.

Comment: hi, any more information needed? thanks..

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just make a UL with images in LIs?

Comment: Hi, because my images are all draggables + resizeable and i already have a lot of function tied to them.. changing the html construct is just too risky.. thanks ya...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found one easy to use plugin, the jScrollPane. Just post it here in case someone is searching for a customize scroll bar that can be applied to different kinds of html construct. Thanks everyone :)